# Prove 'every Positive Definite Matrix is Symmetric BUT not the other way around'

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-explanation, positive-definite

I'm studying Linear Algebra and I read that :

"Every Positive Definite Matrix is Symmetric BUT the vice versa is not correct..."

in the text it suggests using 'x= u +iv' and then prove it by calculating (x,Ax).

how can I prove it this way ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is your definition of *positive definite*? For example, on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix), symmetric (or hermitian)  is part of the definition ...

Comment: in the textbook it says : Positive Definite Matrix = if (x,Ax) > 0

Comment: @Cypher If the expression $(x,Ax) $ is to be understood as the internal product using real numbers, then the "suggestion" does not make sense (it suggest to use complex). But if we allow complex numbers, then the expression $(x,Ax) >0$ does not make sense (because in general it gives a complex number, and a complex number cannot be compared against zero). The standard way is to interpret it as a hermitian internal product, and to assume that $A$ is hermitian as part of the definition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Let us for simplicity assume that $V$ is a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ with an [inner product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space) $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle: V\times V\to \mathbb{F}$. Note that in the complex case the inner product is a [sesquilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sesquilinear_form) (as opposed to a [bilinear form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bilinear_form)).
2. Let us (for the purpose of this answer) define that an $\mathbb{F}$-linear map $A:V\to V$ is *positive* if $$\forall x\in V\backslash\{0\}: ~~ \langle x, Ax\rangle ~>~0.\tag{1}$$
3. Also let us define that $A$ is *symmetric* if $$
   \forall x,y\in V: ~~ \langle y, Ax\rangle ~=~\langle Ay, x\rangle.\tag{2}$$
   In the complex case, the condition (2) is often called *Hermiticity.*
4. $A$ positive does *not* imply that $A$ is symmetric, if the vector space $V$ is real $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{R}$. Here is a 2D counterexample:
   $$\begin{align} \langle x, y\rangle~=~&x^ty~=~x_1y_1+x_2y_2, \quad
    A~=~\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 2 \cr 0 & 2\end{pmatrix},\cr  \langle x, Ax\rangle~=~&(x_1+x_2)^2+ x_2^2.\end{align}\tag{3} $$
5. Assume from now on that $V$ is a *complex* vector space $\mathbb{F}=\mathbb{C}$.
6. Let us (for the purpose of this answer) define that $A$ is *real* if $$\forall x\in V: ~~ {\rm Im}\langle x, Ax\rangle ~=~0.\tag{4}$$
7. $\fbox{$\text{Proposition: }  $A$ \text{ real } ~~\Leftrightarrow~~ $A$ \text{ symmetric.}$}$ The $\Leftarrow$ proof is trivial and left to the reader. The $\Rightarrow$ proof will be deduced in steps below. Assume from now on that $A$ is real.
8. By replacing $x$ with $x+y$ in eq. (4), deduce that
   $$ \forall x,y\in V: ~~ {\rm Im}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle +\langle x, Ay\rangle\right)~\stackrel{(4)}{=}~0.\tag{5}$$
9. By replacing $y$ with $iy$ in eq. (5), deduce that
   $$ \forall x,y\in V: ~~ {\rm Re}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle -\langle x, Ay\rangle\right)~\stackrel{(5)}{=}~0.\tag{6}$$
10. By rewriting $$\langle x, Ay\rangle~=~ \overline{\langle Ay, x\rangle}\tag{7}$$
    in eqs.  (5) & (6), we get
    $$ \forall x,y\in V: ~~ {\rm Im}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle - \langle Ay, x\rangle\right) ~=~{\rm Im}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle + \overline{\langle Ay, x\rangle}\right) ~\stackrel{(5)+(7)}{=}~0,\tag{8}$$
    and
    $$ \forall x,y\in V: ~~ {\rm Re}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle - \langle Ay, x\rangle \right)
    ~=~{\rm Re}\left(\langle y, Ax\rangle - \overline{\langle Ay, x\rangle}\right) ~\stackrel{(6)+(7)}{=}~0,\tag{9}$$
    respectively. Now deduce eq. (2) from eqs. (8) & (9). End of proof.

Comment: Thanks for your proof. but I didn't exactly get what happened in equations 6 and 7. could you please elaborate on them a bit for me? Thanks.

Comment: One needs to use the properties of a sesquilinear form. I updated the answer. Let me know if it is still unclear.